# How to make Vue to see changes in input element if preventDefault was used?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is a very simple example. I do not want to create a newline in textarea when I press enter. That's the reason why I invoke `preventDefault` in my handler. I also modify the value inside of textarea. The problem is the model does not get updated because I used `preventDefault`.
How can I prevent Enter from typing newline and make Vue to see changes in textarea?

Note, that I used `el.value` (update element) instead of `this.value` (Vue model), because I want my cursor to stay on the same position. If I update a model data, the cursor will be reset to the end after rendering view and I can't fix it's position that easy.

I will need a kind of a hack with `$nextTick` to fix cursor position:

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
      el.setSelectionRange(cursorPos, cursorPos);
    })
```

So I do not want to make things complex and do not want to touch **model** and cause view to be re-rendered. Why? I just want to make Vue to notice changes of input's value. I feel like I need to emit some Event manually (trigger input event for my textarea, but how?)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: 'Hello.World'
  },

  methods: {
    fixGreeting(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      let el = evt.target;
      let cursorPos = el.selectionStart;
      el.value = el.value.replace('.', ' ');
      el.setSelectionRange(cursorPos, cursorPos);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <textarea v-on:keydown.enter="fixGreeting" v-model="value"></textarea> Model: {{ value }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found a solution which is clean enough.
At the end of my method code, I just need to add:
`el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));`

And Vue will change model according to element value.

Please let me know in the comments if there are any cons.